# Is there a way to store multiple data in one field in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I have a field(Vehicle Brand Specialty) that stores the brand which mechanics are proficient in, but there could be more than one brand. I know it goes against 1NF to store multiple entries in one field but I could also store the data but separated by commas. What is the best option here?

Comment: 'What is the best option here' - neither of those mentioned , store as a separate row per mechanic/brand

Comment: As any N:N relationship, it should go in a separate table. But based on your question: for some reason do you **have to** use that existing cell and are you unable to change the structure?

Comment: Agreeing with Andrew but FWIW WordPress does this all the time, for example storing an array in the wp_options.options_value column  
If 'correct' relational design isn't an available choice, you could research into how this is managed using APIs etc to populate and unpick. There's plenty of explanation in SO for example (search WordPress Serialized Array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "best" (and the only "right") way to do that in a relational world would be a table linking mechanics and brands. Something along the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE mechanic
             (id integer AUTO_INCREMENT,
              ...
              PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE brand
             (id integer AUTO_INCREMENT,
              ...
              PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE mechanic_brand
             (mechanic integer,
              brand integer,
              ...
              PRIMARY KEY (mechanic,
                           brand),
              FOREIGN KEY (machanic)
                          REFERENCES mechanic
                                     (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (brand)
                          REFERENCES brand
                                     (id));
```